# Check the probability that a system is blocked by errors

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, bayes-theorem

A system is blocked when in a sequence of 4 bit occurs more then 3 errors OR 3 consecutive errors... We know that the probability that an error occur is 0.1 now check the probability that the system can be blocked.

How can I solve this problem? Bayes or binomial approach?
I haven't understand the problem and I'm newbie about this argument...Thank you very much

Comment: Assuming each bit can be erroneous independently with probability $0.1$, what is the probability that $3$ bits out of $4$ are erroneous? If you can figure out this problem, I think the rest of it should follow.

Comment: @sudeep5221 can you help me? I don't know how to formalize a solution

Answer (score 0):

It does seem this can be read in several ways.

Blocked if a specific 4-bit packet has `BBBG`, `GBBB` or `BBBB`?
In that case I get from R probability 0.0019.

```
2*.1^3*.9 + (.1)^4
[1] 0.0019
```

Or is it a continuous stream of bits? Then any three consecutive`B`s
can block. For example `GGBB` immediately followed by `BGGG`.
Then, starting at a randomly chosen point, the probability of
a blockage on at the next bit would depend on assumptions about
the immediate past history.

Comment: Thank you BruceET... can you explain me better your solution? However every sequence is 4 bit and are inedependent events if this can help you

Comment: Then I think my first solution is right. For the 3 listed sequences, probabilities are $(.1)(.1)(.1)(.9),\; (.9)(.1)(.1)(.1),$ and $(.1)^4.$ Just add them.

Comment: I'm trying to do with your help and I have found this... GBBB(0.9*0.1^3), BBBG(0.9*0.1^3) and BBBB (0.1^4) and this is the condition "3 errors sequentially", now how can I solve the second condition? "OR more than 3 errors in a sequence"? Example: BGBB, BBGB etc

Comment: More than three errors is four:`BBBB`.

Comment: Right, absolutely right... is a my stupid error... in case of 5 bits (I'm tryng your method to understand) I have created this solution... GGBBB, GBBBG, BBBGG "3 sequentially errors" BBBBB, GBBBB, BGBBB, BBGBB, BBBGB, BBBBG "more than 3 errors"... is this a good way? Have I missed come combinations?